# Cannot find `libpam`

Tags: 14.04, apt

I am trying to install DB2 Enterprise server 10.5 on my Ubuntu 14.04 Linux VM. I ran a prerequisite check and got the following message:

```
The db2prereqcheck utility failed to find the following 32-bit 
library file: "/lib/libpam.so*".
```

So I did a `sudo apt-get install libpam0g:i386`. However, the system did not update libpam:

```
libpam0g:i386 is already the newest version.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 160 not to upgrade.
```

So it seems like libpam is there. What am I missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your system's libpam is actually in /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpam.so, so if your DB2 expects to find in in /lib it will fail.  Try adding the i386-linux-gnu to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or even put an explicit link in /lib .